# Forcing GPU usage for rendering when using Blender as a python module

Tags: python

On this page https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_advanced_blender_as_bpy.html it is said that:
Resource Sharing (GPU)
It’s possible other Python modules make use of the GPU in a way that prevents Blender/Cycles from accessing the GPU.

I'm running into this issue, only the CPU is being used for rendering when I run my script. The .blend is configured correctly for GPU rendering (I tested it manually) and I'm not changing any render settings in the script.

How can I workaround that? Do I have to change my code to execute Blender as a subprocess (would be very annoying).
I'm not showing code because I don't think it would be relevant and it's a big project so I have lots of files.